# Get Master key Password in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 which has encrypted column.I am getting the encrypted column name, symmetric key name, issuer name , certificate name by using sql query. Now I want to get master key detail and its password by sql  query. Is this possible??Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get Master key password using SQL query. However you can regenerate it using below query.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Your_New_Password';
GO
```

Link for reference : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186937.aspx